# How to set photo to a background-image through a model that is type text

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm quite new at Angular so my concern may seem a little bit simple to solve.
I have an image that I get through google API (si it's not an url), how could i set it to the css tag background-image which only take URI?

Thanks!

Comment: "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem." https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngStyle` directive:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photoURL + ')'}"></div>
```

Or you can use `[style.background-image]`:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + photoURL + ')'"></div>
```